# Slim API POST in php

Tags: php, ajax, http, slim

I made an API through Slim framework and I was testing it using the Advanced Rest Client. Now I want to implement in my php website the API rest. How Can I do that? Is better use AJAX or PHP for that? Can you  give a small code demo?

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate.

I tried this code,is this the best solution: My problem here is that I need to add a header with an authorization key.

```
$data = array("title" => "otro libro", "isbn" => "998-84-8184-1", "author" => "otro autor :)");
    $ch = curl_init("http://localhost/slimrest/books");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if(!$response) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        var_dump($response);
    }
```

Comment: What did  you try yourself?

Comment: just use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);` where `$headers` is an array of headers you want to set in `header: value` format. You can also check out a lightweight PHP REST client I built, which you are welcome to use - https://github.com/mikecbrant/php-rest-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use AJAX. I guess its popular to use a javascript framework like jquery or angular.

You can then just pass your token along as a part of the body.
I am most familar with jquery so heres a link to the docs.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/